# Do yarn workspaces work with npm, too?

Tags: npm, package.json, yarnpkg

I checked out a repo which uses yarn instead of npm as build tool.

in the package.json, it defines workspaces to deal with multiple sub-projects:

```
{
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "dependencies": [],
  "devDependencies": [
    // long list
  ]
}
```

As a result, the root `package.json` does not contain any runtime dependency. Just the `packages/*/package.json` contain those.

To compile (and start in dev mode) I do:

```
yarn install
yarn start
```

I have found no documentation, that `workspaces` is also recognized and correctly used by npm.

Is there a way to make it work with npm, too?

Comment: Npm has a [workspace feature](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-workspace), but there the configuration file is called workspace.json

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt your comment is misleading: that link points to a (third-party) package, not an official feature of the NPM package manager

Comment: @StevenLiekens Right. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @helt Can you please update the accepted answer to the answer from Sahan Amarsha. I think given that it's already end of 2020 current accepted answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: @BohdanTsymbala I hesitated to switch it as my assumption was that npm 7 is not yet the most widely used npm version. Besides that, the fact that there is a new answer does not render the previous answer incorrect - just outdated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Now that npm v7.0.0 is out, npm supports `workspaces`. You can manage multiple packages from within a singular top-level, root package. See more at https://github.blog/2020-10-13-presenting-v7-0-0-of-the-npm-cli/

Your workflows will not get **npm v7.0.0** by default unless you install it using `npm install -g npm@7`.

Comment: I'd be very careful with NPM7 as of now. I've been playing with workspaces for a few days using the very minimal docs available, and the blog post here: https://adfallon.wordpress.com/2020/11/01/simplify-your-monorepo-with-npm-7-workspaces/

On the surface, it seems really exciting, but I haven't been able to make any of this work. In particular, the following absolutely doesn't work, in my testing so far.

"Without workspaces the React app would complain that it cannot find a module named @xyz/ui and would start looking for it in the npm official registry."

Answer (score 19):

Managing dependencies in a monorepo is not supported with npm.  The [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) package can be used to manage JavaScript projects with cross dependencies.  I believe Lerna uses Yarn under the hood, but with Yarn as your project's package manager, this feature is supported out of the box.

Here is a repo that might be helpful to see how Yarn and Lerna work together: https://github.com/Quramy/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example

Comment: `Lerna` works with `npm` as default `npmClient`, but you can setup it to use: `{ "npmClient": "yarn",  "useWorkspaces": true }`

Answer (score 16):

`npm` has plans to implement `workspaces` somewhere along the [v7](https://github.com/npm/cli/tree/release/v7.0.0-beta), hopefully. They've [written](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/186983646370/npm-cli-roadmap-summer-2019) [about it](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/617484925547986944/npm-v7-series-introduction) in their blog and there's [an accepted proposal](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/accepted/0026-workspaces.md).

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020-08-11 Workspaces are available in the v7 beta.

> [RFC 26](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/accepted/0026-workspaces.md) First phase of `workspaces` support is added. This changes
> npm’s behavior when a root project’s `package.json` file contains a
> `workspaces` field.

https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major

You can view and download the beta here:

https://github.com/npm/cli/tags

Answer (score 0):

NPM version 7 support workspace management. Now we can manage our workspace dependencies using npm workspace.

More on the workspace support can be found here official site here.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces

If you are looking for a simple example follow this link

https://github.com/pravanjan/npm-workspace-example/tree/master

Tested using node v16.6.1
npm 7.20.3